# TextView on widget not updating using OnUpdate method

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver, textview

I have a widget showing a digital clock using TextView in which I want to update more frequently than the allowed 30 mins in the xml. I've seen examples but id like someone to help me with my specific problem. The widget is configured correctly and works fine but doesn't update like it should as it is a digital clock.

```
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent clockIntent = new Intent(context, DeskClock.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                clockIntent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.digitalclock);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.gl, pendingIntent);

        java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        String time = "kk:mm";
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime, DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));

        String date = "dd MMMMM yyyy";
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvDate, DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

The xml android:updateperiodmills only updates every 30 mins but i need to update or set the TextView at least every second like ive done using a run method in the main app. Any help is muchly appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

```
public class DigitalClock extends AppWidgetProvider {

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent clockIntent = new Intent(context, DeskClock.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                clockIntent, 0);

        final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.digitalclock);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.gl, pendingIntent);

        final java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        final String time = "kk:mm";
        final String date = "dd MMMMM yyyy";


        BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastTime = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTime,
                        DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));

                views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvDate,
                        DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));
            }
        };

        IntentFilter mTime = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastTime, mTime);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}

private void registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastTime,
        IntentFilter mTime) {

}
}
```

This is now my class but i had to add this method:

```
    private void registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastTime,
        IntentFilter mTime) {

}
```

What do i do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and listen for the [`ACTION_TIME_TICK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) action.

This wil get invoked every minute.

```
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastTime = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Change the time on your widget
        }
    };

IntentFilter mTime = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
registerReceiver(mBroadcastTime, mTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it wants me to create a method? Not sure what im supposed to do with it..?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `AlaramManager` to achieve this functionality.

I used in following way in my clock widget.

**Countdown for alaram :**

```
 class CountSecond extends CountDownTimer
        {
            public CountSecond(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(ClockWidget.CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE);
                 intent.putExtra("theme", SelectedTheme);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("CL1 Service ","--- count finish ");
                //setTimertoUpdate();


                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)ClockWidgetSetting.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                //calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, createClockTickIntent(ClockWidgetSetting.this));
                //finish();

            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        }
```

And intent to call `appwidgetprovider` of widget is as below. So that `onUpdate()` of widget will be called.

```
 private PendingIntent createClockTickIntent(Context context) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ClockWidget.CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE);
            intent.putExtra("theme", SelectedTheme);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            return pendingIntent;
        }
```

Comment: @timmo15 check my answer and notify me whether this helps you or not.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Rahil2952 but im getting alot of errors and your class dosent work for me. Ill have a look for AlarmManager methods and see what i can find..